# Collapse double index after pivot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

After pivoting data I have the following general structure:

```
     company              is_video            is_sponsored
    greenTrue       0              1          0          1
    0   AES         0.101562    0.000000    0.000000    0.0
    1   AIRBUS      0.380952    0.285714    0.000000    0.0
    2   ALFA        0.485944    0.333333    0.000000    0.0
    3   AT&T        0.428571    0.300000    0.000000    0.0
    4   AbbVie      0.382353    0.200000    0.000000    0.0
```

I would like the columns read as follows:

```
company
is_video_NG
is_video_G
is_sponsored_NG
is_sponored_G
```

(G for when greenTrue = 1, NG for when greenTrue = 0)

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the grouped by dataframe you have, df. Then this should solve your problem:

```
a = df.columns
ind = pd.Index([e[0] + e[1] for e in a.tolist()])
df.columns = ind
result = df.reset_index()
```

The result dataframe should have your desired structure.

**EDIT: Thanks to @r-beginners**

To handle number and string combinations,

```
a = df.columns
ind = pd.Index([e[0] + '_' + str(e[1]) for e in a.tolist()])
df.columns = ind
result = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: `[e[0] + '_' + str(e[1]) for e in a.tolist()]`This is necessary because it is a concatenation of a string and a number.